# How to correctly write a type definition for generics of an unknown subtype?

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to write a type definition using generics for data that will be received from a server. The data will have the following shape (For simplicity, assume all data will be like this):

```
interface Commands {
  Foo: IFoo;
  Bar: IBar;
  // More commands of same style
}

interface Command<K extends keyof Commands> {
  header: K;
  data: Commands[K];
}
```

This definition works for commands of known types, but since the data will be received from a server, its type will be unknown at compile time. I have tried to write a type for every possible command, but I haven't found a solution where the compiler will infer the types correctly.

[Typescript playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG9kzYBcyAzmFKAObIC+AsAFCiSyIqoBCcUeyARjxLlKIGg0ZMW0eEmQBhTAFslcEABNSeJsmRZMJDNgDcO5NyiGLpxroD0d5AFlMUFAmWqNWzDDJwlFHIATwAbCCYJJilwGXYFTzV1AB4AaWQIAA9Ib2QAawhg3wSVJNIAPm1bZAALCDh1aBJUm111ODA4EkVS7wBtVIBdGyjGLIAHVzACAFcQBDBgTBASrxT0rJzNfMLinrWK5AAKOoam5FSAGmR2zu7E-qGASnve9crcMzcwGagV-FOjSg11ucDokWijH2SSOAHJ9LDrvhCAZkLC6qFQphYXQnsgHMgAMo1TAzULqZAeJTjYDhJjQjRwiyIvgokjoiCY7G4-GOYmk8nIECYaZUml0ySSgkABUwpFIwH44TImFCM0Wy1ITAJADkIMAwHVeMsgiSyRSxbSIpKwMFxigAKogPLCgDuIAZ6gAjMgALyrJLJApFPyeioxViyR3Ot0eh7qABMVV0gPOwb28dIrRuHS6Af66dDmeGEMlHhA5GQeadLsw7s9Pv9APqQPZCJBuZI+EEljRGKxONoEnLlf4JBrsc9SabtRb53h2BZoK7AiEaIAzF6E+uE17B6NtY4AKKZe0LCAUtykMlgLVlzXTABWpGW45jdbjb2nzg6NQAdFASTKEceLJMgAAMf4AKzIGYujwQhiFIchyAAPx8KmvYLtiHZ3KyxBoi+gQ5p0+5wShFGUSumHssyuF5t2a6wkRKAikaJFwGRkqkK6BoIDUxzPssf6YXinzVAgcCkCgcIIi8ybwSOqoQH+WJUEcQkgH+oJ-iieIEqCZBmoK-AoKAMDQG4FJSWiRjYuR-BuHAeRmLQlJSTJsLMvJ4kIUp4SqZg6madpuZ-j2+mOIZpDGRSpnIOZlkXlWWiwlwPCwg5TkudUbmNPAN5duR-kqWpcI6iKCXUuEgSxOosJPK5pZAA)

---

This solution works, but it is not ideal because there are many different commands and it would be MUCH better if the compiler could do this by itself.

```
type UnknownCommand3 = Command<'Foo'> | Command<'Bar'> // Works but not ideal
const c: UnknownCommand3 = { header: 'Foo', data: { bar: '312321' }}
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [lookup](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) its properties to get the union you want:

```
type UnknownCommand = { [K in keyof Commands]: Command<K> }[keyof Commands];
```

That evaluates to `Command<"Foo"> | Command<"Bar">` and will automatically gain more union members if you add properties to `Commands`.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-sDGZDfMrlxrxKh9cojfEeIAzABGABMc6XC5FncRlIAopkPQsIIz3FR6WBjaNu9MAFZUZZ9n0DsunZztaoAOigSQ0RzeyGSyAABjfABWU4SAAfhHcExwxScYWnflcVRW8gmhDoNxGEgSAQ0dm1RHk4IePkm2rFCUDla00LgDCLCIKg-UtBBqmQI4b2WN9cN-P4SAQOAqBQcdUWnMCmSNPUIDfIl6FY28QDfes3xxMVKXrah7WlEQUFAGBoHcRk+OQAByMxMEMkSRHcOA8haTCmT4gSeWEwweLEiJJMwaS2LkhSm2UpxVKodTGU0iMQB0qA9PzfRjKsMznOQCy6ms05bIaeBTycrDRNzcT3Ok1FTTlCMWQiIIFB0VEyRSqIgA)